# Reference to scope variables when using $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm dynamically building the rows (and sub-rows) of table body using the link function based on an object (an array of objects, actually) attached to the scope.

Here's the structure of the object:

```
$scope.data.results = [
    {
        selected: false
        name: ,
        description: ,
        ... // plus some other object properties
    }, ... // and so on
]
```

Here's my directive:

```
app.directive('dynamicTbody', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch(function(scope) {
            return scope.results;
        }, function(newValue, oldValue) {

            var tbody = '<tbody>';

            angular.forEach(newValue, function(result, index) {

                tbody +=    '<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="what to put here for result.selected"></td>' +
                            '<td>' + result.name + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + result.description + '</td>' +
                            // ... add column for other object properties


            });

            tbody += '</tbody>';

        });

        var existing_tbody = element.find('tbody');
        if (existing_tbody) {
            angular.element(existing_tbody).remove();
        }

        var tbody_elem = angular.element(tbody);
        var compile_tbody = $compile(tbody_elem);
        element.append(tbody_elem);
        compile_tbody(scope);
    });

});
```

Here's my html:

```
<table dynamic-tbody>
    <thead>
        ...
    <thead>
</table>
```

Displaying the rows works fine, especially when I attempt to do the equivalent of expression {{}}. However, I have problem with the checkbox part. When I use angular directives like ng-model, or ng-click, how do I reference `result.selected`?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: this looks like you have a directive that re-invents the built in `ng-repeat` directive, and I don't see what you gain by it.  however, if you absolutely *must* do this in this manner, perhaps reading the code for the built in directive will give you some insight into how it's implemented in the core.

Comment: @Claies I'm constrained to use an old version of 1.1.5 and `ng-repeat-start end` is not available, that's why I'm forced to use `$compile`. The object actually contains nested objects, which should become sub-rows, basically a dynamic tree-view collapsible table, so I can't use a straightforward `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update model when user changes the value of checkbox, your code is not Angular-way.

I would recommend for you to use template instead of $compile service.
The Angular-way makes your code very simple.

You can write HTML like below in your template.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in results">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.selected"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I setup [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/wwzho1f3/5/).

Comment: I have read the reply to Claies. I gradually understand what you want to achieve.
Anyway I still think some better Angular-way can resolve your problem. Therefore please tell us what you want to achieve by using ng-repeat-start|end directive.